# Загрузка изображения посредством $.ajax() + HTML5

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток.

Не получается реализовать загрузку изображений по типу Drag and Drop.

```
<div class=dropzonestand ondragover="changeStyle(event,this);" ondragenter="changeStyle(this);" ondragleave="returnStyle(this);" ondrop="loadImage(event,$(\'#engName\').val(),href,this);">Перетащите файл изображения сюда. Изображение должно иметь форматы: PNG, GIF, JPG, JPEG. Размер не должен превышать 2МБ.</div>
```

Далее, когда пользователь перетащил файл, срабатывает обработчик

```
 function loadImage(event,loadimagename,foi,obj){
    if(event.preventDefault){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    var loadimagedata=event.dataTransfer.files[0];
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type:"POST",
        url:foi+loadimagename,
        data:loadimagedata,
        beforeSend:function(){
            $(obj).text('Ваше изображение загружается. Пожалуйста, подождите...');
        },
        success:function(msg){
            $(obj).removeClass('dropzoneactive').addClass('dropzonestand');
            $(obj).html(msg);
        }
    });

}
```

Но на сервер ничего не приходит, массивы $_POST и $_FILES пустые и никаких значений там нету.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте FormData:

```
var form = new FormData;
form.append("image", event.dataTransfer.files[0]);
```

Comment: P.S.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604622/file-drag-and-drop-event-in-jquery

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло =)